# Custom views in Horizontal scroll view. Is it possible?

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, ios9, custom-view

I am designing an app which has a screen in which I have a horizontal scroll view which I fill with UIViews dynamically depending upon the number of data I have in my array . I did the same via programmatically. I have mentioned my approach below.

1) I put a Scroll view for scrolling horizontally and created a reference for that in my class.

2) I programatically added views as per my code -

```
 var imagevieww = UIImageView()

    @IBOutlet weak var hrzntlscrl: UIView!

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollview: UIScrollView!


    override func viewDidLoad()

    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let viewcount = 15




        for var i = 0; i < viewcount; i++
        {

            let viewnew = UIView(frame: CGRectMake( hrzntlscrl.frame.origin.x+110*CGFloat(i), 0, 100.0, hrzntlscrl.frame.height))
            viewnew.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
            imagevieww = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 10, 100.0, 50))
            imagevieww.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
            viewnew.addSubview(imagevieww)

            scrollview.addSubview(viewnew)
            }

        }
```

So I just wanted to know that instead of creating a view and the corresponding subviews eg. here imageview and setting their location and frame size programatically , Can I have a standard custom view designed in my IB and use any reference of that in my for loop instead of creating one programmatically? If we can do that,can you please give me some steps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This is possible. You can instantiate a class from a nib with

```
let customView: CustomView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("CustomViewNibName", owner: self, options: nil)[safe: 0] as? CustomView
```

You would also need to set the content size of the horizontal scroll view to the combined width of all the views.

But I think that your use case would be better served by using a `UICollectionView` instad of a scroll view, UICollectionView does all this and more in a much simpler implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am very new to iOS development. Can I do that using .xib . As I heard that .xib is much more efficient tham .nib .  In any case I have not tried to do the both due to lack of efficient material with me. Can you please share any link having examples for doing so?

Comment: Yes. Xib is just compiled down to a nib so I find it easier to talk about nibs but you definitely should build with xib.

Comment: Okay please can you share any link for creating custom views using .xib files. It would be of great help to me . Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the link & if we are creating a .xib file then why should I load a nib as you have written in ur above suggested code?

Comment: can you please check this link out & let me know if this is fine - http://iphonedev.tv/blog/2014/12/15/create-an-ibdesignable-uiview-subclass-with-code-from-an-xib-file-in-xcode-6

Comment: the xib is compiled down to a nib so it's actually the nib that's loaded even though you write it in a xib. The function name is just an artefact of an older version of iOS where nib was used